# Lazy Column with Android View in it lags a lot when scrolling

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-view, android-canvas

I have a lazy column with items where each item has its own custom Slider which is implemented using the AndroidView(). The problem is that the slider has its onDraw() Method overridden. Since the onDraw() method runs in the Main thread, during re-composition or scrolling, the UI starts to lag a lot. How can I tackle this?

```
LazyColumn(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), contentPadding = it
            ) {
                itemsIndexed(items = historyState.asReversed())
              { index, history ->
                   HistoryItem(
                        name = history.groupName,
                        progress= history.progress)
              }
              }



 @Composable
    fun HistoryItem(name: String,progress:Float)
    {
Column{
    Text(text = name)

    WaveFormCompose(
    modifier = Modifier
    .weight(0.7F)
    .padding(8.dp),
    progress = progress,
    audioData = someData,
    audioTrack = someByteBuffer,
    onSeekStarted = {onSeekStarted(it)},
    onSeekFinished = {},
    )
}
}
```

The compose function WaveFormCompose() looks like this:

```
        @Composable
        fun WaveFormCompose(
            modifier: Modifier,
            progress: Float,
            audioTrack: ReplayTrack?,
            audioData: ByteBuffer?,
            onSeekStarted: (Float) -> Unit,
            onSeekFinished: (Float) -> Unit,
        ) {
            AndroidView(modifier = modifier,
                factory = { context ->
                    WaveformSlider (context).apply {
                        this.audioData = audioData
                        value = progress
    },
    update ={
    it.value =progress

})
```

Now the class WaveFormSlider is a custom view that extends Google material Slider,and has its onDraw() method overridden.
Inside class

```
class WaveformSlider @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet? = null){
    Slider(context, attrs)

    override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
            if (heights == null) {
                computeHeights()
            }
    
            // Draw waveform
            for (i in 0 until (heights?.size ?: 0)) {
                val height = heights?.get(i) ?: 0.0f
                if (height > 0) {
                    drawWaveformLine(canvas, i, height)
                }
            }
    
            super.onDraw(canvas)
        } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reversed operation is a heavy operation and should be done as follows:

```
val reversedList = remember(historyState) {  historyState.asReversed() }
```

please check this and notify me

Comment: This one did make the list load smoothly, but it is still lagging when scrolling. If I use default Compose slider, the lagging is gone. But again, if I make a custom compose element in a Box with constraints with slider and canvas, I can see the lagging.

Comment: If it possible upload your code into a repo, i will check it